# Space character before enter in input line

Tags: c

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

const char* CardColour[] = { "green", "blue", "red", "violet", "yellow", "white", "black" };

typedef struct _card {
    int colour;
    int value;
} card;

typedef struct _deck {
    int num_cards;
    card** cards;
} deck;


int main()
{
    card* make_card(int colour, int value);
    deck* make_standard_deck(int k, int g, int gv, int o, int oNumbers[]);
    deck* make_players_hand(int k, int g, int o);
    void deal_cards_players(deck * standardDeck, deck ** playerDeck, int numberOfCards, int numberOfPlayers);
    int check_card(char* temp);

    card* tempCard = NULL;
    tempCard = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
    tempCard->colour = -1;
    tempCard->value = -1;

    int lineCount;
    int a = 0, b=0, CurrentPlayer, ActivePlayer, tempInt=0;
    char ch[20], tempChar[10];
    char useless[10];
    int n=0, k=30, g=30, gv=0, o=30;

    scanf("%s%s%s%d", &useless, &useless, &useless, &ActivePlayer);
    scanf("%s%s%s%d", &useless, &useless, &useless, &n);
    int numberOfPlayers = n;
    int numberOfCards = k * o + g;

    //player 
     deck** PlayerDeck = (deck**)malloc(n * (sizeof(deck)));
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
       PlayerDeck[i] = NULL;
    }
    deck** PlayerHand = (deck**)malloc(n * (sizeof(deck)));
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        PlayerHand[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {   //initialize player hands
        PlayerDeck[i] = make_players_hand(k, g, o);
        PlayerHand[i] = make_players_hand(k, g, o);
    }

//read input 
    lineCount = 0;
    while (lineCount < 2*n) {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        scanf("%d%s%s%s", &CurrentPlayer, &useless, &useless, &useless);

        while ((*ch = getchar()) != 10)    // Evaluate all cards until enter is pressed
        {
            if (lineCount % 2 == 0) {
                scanf("%d", &tempInt);
                fflush(stdout);
                scanf("%s", &tempChar);
                fflush(stdout);
                tempCard->value = tempInt;
                tempCard->colour = check_card(tempChar);
                PlayerDeck[CurrentPlayer - 1]->cards[a] = tempCard;
                PlayerDeck[CurrentPlayer - 1]->num_cards++;
                a++;
            }
            if (lineCount % 2 == 1) {
                scanf("%d", &tempInt);
                fflush(stdout);
                scanf("%s", &tempChar);
                fflush(stdout);
                tempCard->value = tempInt;
                tempCard->colour = check_card(tempChar);
                PlayerHand[CurrentPlayer - 1]->cards[b] = tempCard;
                PlayerHand[CurrentPlayer - 1]->num_cards++;
                b++;
            }
        }
        lineCount++;
    }
//print
    CurrentPlayer = 1;
    while (CurrentPlayer <= n) {
        cout << CurrentPlayer << " player has " << PlayerDeck[CurrentPlayer-1]->num_cards << " on hand " << endl;
        cout << CurrentPlayer << " player has " << PlayerHand[CurrentPlayer-1]->num_cards << " in front of him " << endl;
        CurrentPlayer++;
    }

    free(PlayerDeck);
    free(tempCard);
    return 0;
}

card* make_card(int colour, int value)
{
    card* newCard = NULL;
    newCard = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
    newCard->colour = colour;
    newCard->value = value;

    return newCard;
}

deck* make_standard_deck(int k, int g, int gv, int o, int oNumbers[])
{
    deck* newDeck = NULL;
    newDeck = (deck*)malloc(sizeof(deck));    //make a deck

    newDeck->num_cards = NULL;
    newDeck->num_cards = k * o + g; //number of cards
    newDeck->cards = NULL;
    newDeck->cards = (card**)malloc(newDeck->num_cards * sizeof(card*));    //alocate memore for each card

    int index = 0;

    for (int value = 1; value <= g; value++)
        newDeck->cards[index++] = make_card(0, gv);

    for (int colour = 1; colour <= k; colour++)
        for (int value = 0; value < o; value++)
            newDeck->cards[index++] = make_card(colour, oNumbers[value]);

    return newDeck;
}
deck* make_players_hand(int k, int g, int o)
{
    deck* newDeck = NULL;
    newDeck = (deck*)malloc(sizeof(deck));    //make a deck

    newDeck->num_cards = NULL;
    newDeck->num_cards = k * o + g; //maximum number of cards in player's hand
    newDeck->cards = NULL;
    newDeck->cards = (card**)malloc(newDeck->num_cards * sizeof(card*));
    newDeck->num_cards = 0; //number of cards a player has in his hand right now

    return newDeck;
}

void deal_cards_players(deck* standardDeck, deck** playerDeck, int numberOfCards, int numberOfPlayers) {
    int Player=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {
        playerDeck[Player]->cards[int(i/numberOfPlayers)] = standardDeck->cards[i];
        playerDeck[Player]->num_cards++;
        Player++;
        Player = Player % (numberOfPlayers);
        
    }
}

int check_card(char* temp) {
    int i = 0;
    while (strncmp(temp, CardColour[i], sizeof(temp)) == 0) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Input

active player = 1

players number = 3

1 player hand cards: 4 green 4 green 4 green 1 blue 2 blue 4 blue 5 blue 7 blue 1 red 2 red

1 player deck cards: 5 red 7 red 1 violet 2 violet 4 violet 5 violet 7 violet

2 player hand cards: 4 green 4 green 4 green 1 blue 2 blue 5 blue 7 blue 1 red 2 red 4 red 5 red 7 red 1 violet 2 violet 4 violet

2 player deck cards: 7 violet

3 player hand cards: 4 green 4 green 1 blue 2 blue 4 blue 5 blue 7 blue 1 red 2 red 4 red 5 red 7 red 1 violet 2 violet 5 violet

3 player deck cards: 5 violet 7 violet

This is the part of code and example input I'm working with.

It assigns first 4 inputs to the fifth line and then comes a while loop assigning input of both int and string. I don't know how many cards will be typed by the user that's why I use `while ((*ch = getchar()) != 10)` to check when 'enter' is pressed.

Problem comes when at the end of input is a space character(' '). While loop doesn't break and it keeps assigning values from the next line to previous player. I have no idea how to work around input lines with space at the end which is needed for me to solve this assignment.

EDIT: the only thing I found that might help was fflush() but it doesn't work in this case

Comment: There's no `main()` function.  If I can't cut-n-paste your code and compile it, it's not worth the time to even read the question.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I edited my post so it does compile now

Comment: That's C all the way, except for the two pointless lines `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`. Have you considered studying some basic C++?

Comment: @molbdnilo In this assignment we are allowed to use only pure C with expection to '#include <iostream>' and 'using namespace std;'. It is the only C++ thing we can use. It is wierd for me but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just let the scanf consume all trailing whitespace. eg, instead of `scanf("%s", &tempChar);`, you could use `scanf("%9s ", tempChar)`.  This has the added benefit of avoiding the buffer overflow by using a width on the conversion specifier.  By adding the trailing whitespace, all whitespace (including the newline) will be consumed, so you'll need to change the logic on your while loop.  Probably, you'll want to control the loop by checking the return value of the scanf.  (Always check the value returned by scanf to make sure it actually read the data you expect.)

edit -- adding some details

Looking at your while loop, I'm a bit confused.  You have these counters a and b, but it seems that the second card you read will set  `PlayerHand[CurrentPlayer - 1]->cards[b] = tempCard;`, and when b == 0 that overwrites the previously read card.  Perhaps you intend to be throwing away every other card, but I suspect you intend those to be going to different places.  In either case, you need to simplify that loop and just write something like:

```
scanf("%d%*s%*s%*s", &CurrentPlayer);                                      
while( 2 == scanf("%d%9s ", &tempInt, tempChar)) {                         
        tempCard->value = tempInt;                                         
        tempCard->colour = check_card(tempChar);                           
        PlayerDeck[CurrentPlayer - 1]->cards[linecount%2] = tempCard;                
        PlayerDeck[CurrentPlayer - 1]->num_cards++;                        
}
```

Comment: Will while loop work with last input line if it is controlled by scanf? 'scanf("%9s ", tempChar)' consumes newline as well so from what I understand there will be nothing to read and program will keep on waiting for input like it does now when space is typed at the end of input line.

Comment: If you reach the end of input, `scanf` will return immediately.  You need to check the value returned by scanf to know how many input items were matched.

Comment: I don't know the input size so I can't check whether number of inputs is correct or not. I've tried using scanf to check when does the user press enter but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, you can.  If you have 5 conversion specifiers in the format string, then you expect scanf to return 5.  If it does not, then you either have badly formatted data or you have reached the end of the input stream.

Comment: I'm begginer in C so it may be obvious but after trying it I still can't imagine how it should work. From what You said I understood that after pressing enter my conversion specifier will not match scanf return value but still I have no idea how to implement it since there are multiple scanf used.

Comment: Part of your problem is the multiple scanfs!  Simplify the design.  I'll edit the answer with more detail.

Comment: Every other line is either a player's hand or player's deck that's why there are two different ifs. I edited example input cause the way I've written it could be misleading. This is only one input with 8 lines. 2 first lines are basic information about the state of the game and the next 6 lines provide information about players' decks and hands. Code works even with space at the end of input but it ends after the 4th line of input(1 player deck cards: ...).

Comment: You do not need or want two different `ifs`.  Much of that code is redundant.  The only difference between the two is the location to which you are writing, and you should factor out the commonality.

Comment: Yes of course but the problem I described with the code provided but you is that program ends after 4th line of input while there are 4 more when I write 'while( 2 == scanf("%d%9s ", &tempInt, tempChar))' this line in my code.